# Does IQueryable object in Entity Framework show SQL in Visual Studio?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

When we debug linq to Sql entities , we get to see actual queries getting constucted behind the screen when we hover over IQueryable object, Is there any way where we can see generated sql for EF?

Apart from LinqPad & SQL profiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`.ToTraceString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx):

```
query.ToTraceString()
```

That will return the SQL.

Comment: looks like this method is not available on IQueryable<T> or am i missing something here?

Comment: You haven't shown any code, but it's a member of `ObjectQuery<T>`, per my link.  If you show us your code we can help more.